# Which NoSQL database for Java needs the least amount of setup?

Tags: java, nosql

I'm looking for a NoSQL database for Java which meets these requirements:

- Fully embedded (no need to start an external server)
- No special setup necessary; Ideally, it should work by just giving it a path to a work directory.
- Support for no or partial schema: Users must be able to add/remove special fields to any document
- Support to store any JSON document (which I think is a given)
- Database size will be roughly 1-10MB
- Queries will be JavaScript code that returns `true` for matching documents.
- In a pinch, I'd like to hear your personal opinion how "easy" it is to work with your choice

Comment: You might want to specify that you want to query the json document using a query language or an API since it doesn't seem to be obvious if looking at the answers.

Answer (score 4):

For the last possible setup, you can do all that in plain Java.  Personally that would be the easiest to learn/maintain.

Can you include some requirements which make using a NoSQL library essential?

```
public class FileSystemNoSQL {
    private final File basePath;
    private final Map<String, String> documents = new TreeMap<String, String>();

    public FileSystemNoSQL(File basePath) {
        this.basePath = basePath;
        basePath.mkdirs();

        try {
            for (File file : basePath.listFiles()) {
                documents.put(file.getName(), FileUtils.readFileToString(file));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    public String get(String key) {
        return documents.get(key);
    }

    public void put(String key, String content) {
        try {
            FileUtils.write(new File(basePath, key), content);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
        documents.put(key, content);
    }

    public Map<String, String> findKeyContains(String text) {
        Map<String, String> set = new TreeMap<String, String>();
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry: documents.entrySet())
            if (entry.getKey().contains(text))
                set.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        return set;
    }

    public Map<String, String> findContains(String text) {
        Map<String, String> set = new TreeMap<String, String>();
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry: documents.entrySet())
            if (entry.getKey().contains(text) || entry.getValue().contains(text))
                set.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        return set;
    }

    public static void main(String ... args) {
        char[] spaces = new char[10240];
        Arrays.fill(spaces, ' ');
        String blank10k = new String(spaces);

        // build a database
        long start1 = System.nanoTime();
        FileSystemNoSQL fileSystemNoSQL1 = new FileSystemNoSQL(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), "no-sql"));
        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
            fileSystemNoSQL1.put("key: "+i, "value: "+i + blank10k);
        }
        long time1 = System.nanoTime() - start1;
        System.out.printf("Took %.3f seconds to build a database of 10 MB%n", time1 / 1e9);

        // reload the database
        long start2 = System.nanoTime();
        FileSystemNoSQL fileSystemNoSQL2 = new FileSystemNoSQL(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), "no-sql"));
        long time2 = System.nanoTime() - start2;
        System.out.printf("Took %.3f seconds to load a database of 10 MB%n", time2/1e9);

        // perform queries
        long start3 = System.nanoTime();
        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
            Map<String, String> contains = fileSystemNoSQL1.findKeyContains("key: " + i);
            if (contains.size() < 1) throw new AssertionError();
        }
        long time3 = System.nanoTime() - start3;
        System.out.printf("Took %.3f seconds to scan the keys of a database of 10 MB%n", time3/1e9);

        long start4 = System.nanoTime();
        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
            Map<String, String> contains = fileSystemNoSQL1.findContains("value: " + i + ' ');
            if (contains.size() != 1) throw new AssertionError();
        }
        long time4 = System.nanoTime() - start4;
        System.out.printf("Took %.3f seconds to brute force scan of a database of 10 MB%n", time4/1e9);
    }
}
```

prints

```
Took 0.171 seconds to build a database of 10 MB
Took 0.088 seconds to load a database of 10 MB
Took 0.030 seconds to scan the keys of a database of 10 MB
Took 3.872 seconds to brute force scan of a database of 10 MB
```

Doing a brute force scan is the worst case.  You can build application specific indexes fairly easily which can cut the time to sub-millisecond.

Comment: I need to be able to store any kind of JSON. My documents are only partially structured, so a column/schema based approach doesn't make sense.

Comment: IMHO, The simplest approach is to store documents in files.  They can be as unstructured as you like. Since your dataset is small, I would load them all into memory on restart.  You could index them in memory or brute force your searches and still be pretty fast.  You should be able to scan 10 MB of text in less than 0.1 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully used H2 DB. Is pretty fast and easy to use. It should meet your requirements, here is [feature comparison matrix](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#comparison).

Comment: Well, I guess I could write my own NoSQL database by storing the data into a H2 CLOB column :-/